# jQuery.load() Isn't Working on Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm playing around with Chrome Extensions so I did this *popup.html*:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    var request;

    // Get the current tab information
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        request = tab.url;
    });


    $("#page").load(request, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            $("#page").html("Sorry but there was an error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
</script>

<span id="page"></span>
```

The problem is that when I click the button on the toolbar it just displays a tiny blank square popup. I tried to Inspect Popup but there were no errors on the debug console. What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it permission to access *.jquery.com

Comment: Give it permissions to star.star

Comment: are you sure you loaded it again?